# overflow-y: scroll creating scrollbar when content that is past the max-height is visibility: hidden

Tags: html, css

I have a parent container with `overflow-y: scroll`, and within that parent container content including a button, that when clicked, adds `visibility: visible`, and shows a wall of text. That text *is* hidden, but you can still see the scrollbar up to where it would be unhidden while it is hidden. This is fixed when adding `display: none` to the aforementioned wall of text and `display: block` on-clicked, but that does not allow the opacity animation to go through as display can't be animated. Are there any alternatives?

Essentially, even when the wall of text that would past the overflow is hidden through visibility, the parent container still detects it and adds an overflow-y scrollbar. Through adding display: none it is fixed, but then the animation for the appearance of the wall of text is broken. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

`visibility: hidden` will hide the contents, but still "reserve"  the space it would need, as you correctly observed.

To do an opacity transition as you describe, you could simultaneously do a `height` transition, adding `height: 0` to the default (hidden) state and `height: auto` to the visible state. (using `transition: all ...`)

Comment: You can also add comma separated values in ***transisition*** `transition: opacity 1s linear, height auto ease-in, etc...`